# ActiveAndroid column naming convention for a multi-word column name

Tags: android, activeandroid

I am using ActiveAndroid to build the SQLite database for my Todo Android app. I need to name a column "due_date" but am not sure how to name it in the annotation. Here is a snippet of my Item model:

```
@Table(name = "Items")
public class Item extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "?")
    private Date dueDate;
...
```

What should the 'name' part of my Column annotation be for the dueDate field? Should it be "DueDate" or "Due_Date" or "Due Date"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely up to you. But do not use spaces and other special characters.

I recommended to follow the same style everywhere, so `Items`, `Name`,`DueDate`, `DueDateWhatever`,...

Comment: Is it referring to the column name in SQLite?

Comment: `@Column(name = "blahblah")` is referring to the column name in SQLite file.